# Updating a device to iOS 11.2 breaks support with Xcode 9.1

Tags: ios, iphone

I tried to run my app on a device running iOS 11.2 and received the following error:

> **Could not locate device supported files.**
>
> This iPhone 5s (Model A1457, A1518, A1528, A1530) is running iOS 11.2
>   (15C114), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode.

I have used iphone 5s(version 11.1.2) and I want to build my project from xcode 9.1(ios 11.1).

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems that Apple released iOS 11.2 to the public without releasing Xcode 9.2 yet (the Mac App Store reports 9.1 as latest at the time of this writing), which includes the iOS 11.2 SDK necessary to target devices running iOS 11.2. You should be able to run this on your device with the Xcode 9.2 beta, which you can download from the [developer download page](https://developer.apple.com/download/) if you have a developer account

**EDIT:** Xcode 9.2 is publicly available now, and you can download it from the [Mac App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12)

Answer (score 2):

Xcode 9.2 has finally been released. You can update it from App Store or just download it here: https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_9.2/Xcode_9.2.xip

Comment: I have downloaded and also checked with Xcode_9.2. When I create a 'Single View App' it's ok and build(iphone 5s) without any problem. But problem occur when I create cocos2dx with box2d project.

Comment: Beware! Xcode 9.2 is still a beta. So although you will be able to build for iOS 11.2, you will not be able to submit builds to Apple.

Comment: @AndrewDuncan it says that it's release version here: https://itunes.apple.com/tr/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12 (however, the actual build ends with "b" when I install. something cheesy going on)

Comment: Yep something is out of sync. I tried to upload a build to iTunesConnect and got the failure alert "Can't submit app built with beta tools."

Comment: @AndrewDuncan I really don't want to believe that Apple rushed Xcode 9.2 so fast that they've actually released a beta build as a release version.

Answer (score 1):

I have Xcode9.2 on my MacBook and 8 on my MacMini. So I just copied the 11.2 DeviceSupport DeveloperDiskImage .dmg and .signature from the MacBook to the MacMini. Worked fine.

Comment: where did you download the disk image from?

Comment: It's automatically added to /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport when xcode is updated. So I just took the version from Xcode 9 and put it in my Xcode 8 on the other computer.

Answer (score 0):

For the rookies like me, if you get a message similar to this:

*"This iPhone 6 is running iOS 11.2.X, which may not be supported by this version of Xcode."*

It means you have to update Xcode.

I hit this problem when my phone was running 11.2.6 and I was running Xcode Version 9.0

You can update it from App Store or just download it here: https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_9.2/Xcode_9.2.xip

Answer (score 0):

Get the device support file from here if latest available [Device Support File](https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport)

Answer (score 0):

Any one having this kind of Error when your device OS version is updated and Your **Xcode** version is not.

[image]

Xcode - Version 9.1 (9B55)
Device Version - 11.3

**Solution:**

Find your friends who have latest **Xcode 9.x**

From following ways you can get device support files

1. Go to Finder and Search

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/

2. Right click on Xcode -> Show Package Contents then navigate to Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/11.X 
   Copy the 11.X

Please note **X** - will be Versions

Also you can download from this link - https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport/issues/7

After you get device supporting files, Add all the new version to yours Xcode **DeviceSupport** folder

Restart the Xcode and You are Ready to debug :)